# How to navigate to nested screen in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to navigate to another screen with in my album component when the user click
on a album but I keep getting this error

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"AlbumScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.
```

below is my code and my try

navigation->Album->index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import styles from './style';
import { Album, TabOneParamList } from '../../types';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
// import Navigation from '../navigation';

export type AlbumProps = {
    album: Album,

}

const AlbumComponent = (props: AlbumProps) => {

    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const onPress = () => {

        navigation.navigate('AlbumScreen');
    }



    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={{ uri: props.album.imageUri }} style={styles.image} />
                <Text style={styles.text}>{props.album.artistsHeadline}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}






export default AlbumComponent;
```

here is my AlbumScreen.tsx  also this is the screen I want to user to move to once they click on the Album

```
import React from 'react';

import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const AlbumScreen = () => (
    <View>
        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }} >Hello from Album Screen</Text>
    </View>
);



export default AlbumScreen;
```

also here is my  BottomTabNavigation which I add the newly created AlbumScreen just the way the HomeScreen is added

```
import {
  Ionicons,
  Entypo,
  EvilIcons,
  MaterialCommunityIcons,
  FontAwesome5,
  FontAwesome
} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import * as React from 'react';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import useColorScheme from '../hooks/useColorScheme';
import TabOneScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import AlbumScreen from '../screens/AlbumScreen';
import TabTwoScreen from '../screens/TabTwoScreen';
import { BottomTabParamList, TabOneParamList, TabTwoParamList } from '../types';

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<BottomTabParamList>();

export default function BottomTabNavigator() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: Colors[colorScheme].tint }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={TabOneNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <Entypo name="home" size={30} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="store"
        component={TabTwoNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="store" size={30} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Library"
        component={TabTwoNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <Ionicons name="library-outline" size={30} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={TabTwoNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <FontAwesome name="user-circle" size={28} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}



// Each tab has its own navigation stack, you can read more about this pattern here:
// https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab
const TabOneStack = createStackNavigator<TabOneParamList>();

function TabOneNavigator() {
  return (
    <TabOneStack.Navigator>
      <TabOneStack.Screen
        name="TabOneScreen"
        component={TabOneScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: 'Home' }}
      />
       <TabOneStack.Screen
        name="AlbumScreen"
        component={AlbumScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: 'Album' }}
      />
    </TabOneStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const TabTwoStack = createStackNavigator<TabTwoParamList>();

function TabTwoNavigator() {
  return (
    <TabTwoStack.Navigator>
      <TabTwoStack.Screen
        name="TabTwoScreen"
        component={TabTwoScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: 'Tab Two Title' }}
      />
    </TabTwoStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Here is the picture of what I am trying to do I want upon clicking on the album on the right of this image the user is direct to another screen but I keep getting the Highlighted error [my errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YP8E.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify which stack you are targeting when you attempt to navigate.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator